# Error "URI malformed" usando decodeURIComponent Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Saludos tengo un problema al querer decodificar una url, la url es la siguiente:

```
url="https://d28lcskf99qb3s.cloudfront.net/phantomx-seguridad-api/seg/v1/roles?codigoEmpresa=1&esActivo=T&codigoAplicacion=1&tipoFiltro=nombreRol&page=1&perPage=16&valorFiltro=%"
```

el codigo que utilizo para decodificar es:

```
codificarUrl(url){
    let codurl=encodeURIComponent(url);
    let urlCod=decodeURIComponent(codurl);
    let urlCodF=decodeURI(urlCod);
    return urlCod;
  }
```

ahi me sale el error de "URI malformed" no encuentro donde está el error espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Es correcto que se genere el error `URI malformed` ya que se está intentando decodificar (`decodeURI`) una cadena de texto que no ha sido codificada (`encodeURI`), esto ha sido especificado en la documentación:

> Decodifica un Identificador de Recurso Uniforme (Uniform Resource Identifier, URI) previamente creado por `encodeURI` o por una rutina similar.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURI

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/decodeURI